# Harmonics modelling in electrical machines

Tags: harmonics, pmsm, modelling

I am currently working with a permanent magnet synchronous machine and I am trying  to model the harmonics caused by magnetic saturation, dead time, and non linearities of the frequency inverter.

It is known that for a three phase machine, these harmonics have order 1, 5, 7,... (The fifth harmonic is negative sequence and the seventh is positive sequence). Since I already have a Simulink model of the machine, I intend to use the superposition principle to add the harmonics to my current model.

My question is : what is the correct way to model these harmonics? I've checked the literature, and there are some authors that use:

$$
\left\{ 
     \begin{array}{ll} 
            I_a(t) = I_1\cos{(\omega t + \theta_1)} + I_5\cos{(5\omega t + \theta_5)} + I_7\cos{(7\omega t + \theta_7)} \\
            I_b(t) = I_1\cos{(\omega t - \frac{2\pi}{3} + \theta_1)} + I_5\cos{(5\omega t + \frac{2\pi}{3} + \theta_5)} + I_7\cos{(7\omega t - \frac{2\pi}{3} + \theta_7)}  \\
           I_c(t) = I_1\cos{(\omega t + \frac{2\pi}{3} + \theta_1)} + I_5\cos{(5\omega t - \frac{2\pi}{3} + \theta_5)} + I_7\cos{(7\omega t + \frac{2\pi}{3} + \theta_7)}
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

And others use:

$$
\left\{ 
     \begin{array}{ll} 
            I_a(t) = I_1\cos{(\omega t + \theta_1)} + I_5\cos{(5\omega t + \theta_5)} + I_7\cos{(7\omega t + \theta_7)} \\
            I_b(t) = I_1\cos{(\omega t - \frac{2\pi}{3} + \theta_1)} + I_5\cos{(5\omega t + {\color{red} 5}\frac{2\pi}{3} + \theta_5)} + I_7\cos{(7\omega t - {\color{red} 7}\frac{2\pi}{3} + \theta_7)}  \\
           I_c(t) = I_1\cos{(\omega t + \frac{2\pi}{3} + \theta_1)} + I_5\cos{(5\omega t - {\color{red} 5}\frac{2\pi}{3} + \theta_5)} + I_7\cos{(7\omega t + {\color{red} 7}\frac{2\pi}{3} + \theta_7)}
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

And others include these harmonics in the voltage.

What is the reason behind multiplying or not the phase displacement (\$2\pi/3\$) by \$n\$ (the harmonics order)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is the phase displacement in a 3phase system.
Each harmonic also needs to be shifted by +-120degrees (2π/3)

Comment: So, the first representation would be correct, because it already takes into account the phase shift of \$2\pi/3\$ multiplied by \$n\$, right?